# Static data but not for changing api data?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, next.js, blogs

I was creating a blog with nextjs MongoDB and express. I used `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` to generate pages dynamically and display each blog on a separate page. but after deployment, if I add or remove a blog from the API then. it is not reflected on the website until the next deployment.

Comment: Can you share your code for getStaticProps and getStaticPath?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior when using Next to build a static site. At build time, it's going to use `getStaticPaths` to generate a list of all the available pages for your blog, and then it will build each one into an html file using `getStaticProps` data. From that point forward, `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` won't run again (they run in development mode, but not when you build and export your site).

So when you delete or add a blog post, the static website doesn't know anything about that because it's just a "dumb" set of html files. You have generally two options:

1. Set up a build pipeline that listens for changes (add, remove, update) to your blog content and rebuilds your site when the content changes, or
2. Switch to using Next in SSR mode instead of SSG mode, which would allow you to use `getServerSideProps` which runs on every page load and which would update immediately as your content changes.

That second one (using SSR) requires you to run your Next site on a node server like Vercel or Firebase Functions or something similar versus how you have it now (SSG) where it's just a bunch of html files and javascript and can be hosted in places like Github pages or Amazon S3.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) as another possible solution when using `getStaticProps`/`getStaticPaths`.